# UNC path to File URI

Tags: file, uri, unc

how to convert UNC path to File URI..
For my application user will give css UNC path like this in test box :

```
\\egng4573\D$\CSS\Style.css
```

how can i change it to :

```
file:///D:/CSS/Style.css
```

so that firefox and IE both can access css from the desired path and apply on them..
please tell....

Comment: You are aware that this will only work on the machine named `egng4573`? If you are having problems with this, it might be because of security restrictions, not because of problems with the path itself. Maybe elaborate on the context

Comment: make it generalize....\\server\drive$\location.. ====>> file:///drive:/location......this is i wanted to ....actuallly i dont kno wat user gonna enter as unc path...nd this unc path works in IE but not in FF ....dats why i wanted it to change it to File URI...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .NET,

```
let unc = @"\\egng4573\D$\CSS\Style.css"
```

then

```
new System.Uri(unc)
```

should do it.

```
val it : System.Uri = file://egng4573/D$/CSS/Style.css
```